# Schema in sql with spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Is it necessary to always put Schema in sql queries? The `SimpleJdbcTemplate` seems to work on local with schema but fails in other machine. What could be the reason? Database is oracle and it is running on JBoss AS.

Comment: I can't answer for Oracle Databases but certainly with other databases (Sybase and MySQL) I have never used the schema values. It might be down to the individual database driver.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax is dependent only on the type of database. For Oracle you do not need to specify a schema if the referenced object (e.g. table, view) is in your current schema or a local or public synonym exists for it. If not then you have to reference the object as `[schema].[object]`.